# Custom Validation connected to database working on localhost but not on remote sever

Tags: codeigniter

I have created MY_Form_validation that extends CI_Form_validation. I have loaded the library in Customer Controller. The validate_email function in customer model checks whether the customer exists while logging in. It is working fine on localhost but the method always returns false on the remote server even when a user actually exists. What could be wrong?

I have loaded the library like this

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

Login email validation rules

```
  $validate_data = array(

        array(

            'field' => 'login_email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|validate_email|is_active|xss_clean'
        )
 );
```

My_Form_validation library

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

public function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();        

}    

public function validate_email($field){

    $this->CI->load->model('customer_model');

    $email = $this->CI->customer_model->validate_email($field);

    if($email === true){

        return true;
    }else{

        $this->set_message('validate_email','The {field} does not exist');
        return false;
    }


}//end method validate_email
}
?>
```

Validate email model function

```
public function validate_email($email){

    $sql = "SELECT `customer_id` FROM `customer` WHERE `email` = ? AND `status` != -1";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($email));
    return ($query->num_rows() == 1) ? true : false;

}//end method validate_email
```

I like using -1 to represent deleted accounts in my databases

I am also autoloading my database

Comment: Well, didn't you forget to change the local settings of the database in your server environment?

Comment: I changed the settings correctly. Data is being inserted for example in the case of registration but all validation functions in the library connected to the database arent working

Comment: Then show us the `validate_email()` model function.

Comment: @Linesofcode theres my function

Comment: does anything happen in the db?

Comment: @Vali yes. I did a test registration and data was inserted into the db

Comment: could it be that the record is doubled? If it returns 2 (or more) records, it would return false. Try **return($query->num_rows() >= 1)?true:false**

Comment: @Vali..That was my suspicion at first so i deleted all data so now I have only one customer. Plus that would not be correct logically because in reality there should be only one user with that email address

Comment: ofcourse, I ment that for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the a similar problem. According to the database configurations in codeigniter database.php, I noticed the following

```
 char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

So i dropped my database and recreated it. Changed my database collation to `utf8_general_ci` and changed my tables charset from `armscii8` to `utf8` and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

By trusting your words about the data that is currently on your database your function should work, but I would advise you to change the model validate function to something more similiar to CodeIgniter approach.

```
public function validate_email($email)
{
   $this->db->where('email', $email)
            ->where('status !=', '-1');

   $query = $this->db->get('customer');

   if($query->num_rows() > 0)
      return TRUE;
}
```

Secondly, create a function to retrieve all the results according to your `where` condition.

```
public function getAllEmailsByEmail($email)
{
   $this->db->where('email', $email)
            ->where('status !=', '-1');

   return $this->db->get('customer')->result();
}
```

And just check out many rows it's returned.

```
print_r($this->CI->customer_model->getAllEmailsByEmail($field));
```

Comment: I disagree with the need to use Query Builder (or Active Record in CI v < 3) to make the db call. The OP's approach is just as valid.